# vim filetype settings lost when resourcing vimrc

Tags: vim

Following the instructions [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/44.html) I have an ftdetect file, `~/.vim/ftdetect/cheat.vim` with this line:

`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cheat/* set filetype=cheat`

This loads a simple config file at `~/.vim/ftplugin/cheat.vim`:

```
set statusline=%t
set statusline+=\ %P
set statusline+=%#todo#
set nonumber
```

It loads fine, but when I source `~/.vimrc` the settings for `cheat.vim` are lost.

Comment: I should add that I'm using neovim which is using the vim configuration.

Comment: On a whim, I put the lines in `ftplugin/cheat.vim` into `ftdetect/cheat.vim` and it works better but I'm still losing the highlighting.

Comment: Why are you sourcing your vimrc? Also, do you mean your settings in a cheat file are lost or your settings while editing the ftplugin cheat.vim are lost?

Comment: If I'm editing a cheat file and then when I reload the .vimrc file, settings are lost. I'm getting somewhere, though. I added a `set filetype=cheat` on a line by itself in the ftdetect file and that helped. I'm still losing the statusline+=%#todo# setting, though. The color of the status bar changes when I reload .vimrc. So I still have something misconfigured.

Comment: Also, I'm noticing settings from the cheat file are bleeding over into the other config files now. What a pain.

Comment: Thats because you forgot setlocal (im not sure if statusline can be local). Theres no reason to source vimrc?

Comment: I source vimrc when I change it so I don't have to close a file and reopen it. Though I just discovered when I do :e to edit the file it does what I want. I'll try out the local setting.

Comment: Yes :e can fix it... the statusline gets reset in your vimrc. Presumably

Comment: OK, I think I understand what's happening now. I got this line in .vimrc: nnoremap <silent> sv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>. That's going to a file called /Users/me/.config.nvim/init.vim. That file probably isn't loading ftplugin settings is my guess.

Comment: Sure it is... but vimrc type stuff is meant to load once at startup. Writing a vimrc that doesnt “break” when re-sourced is a worthy challenge. The trick is, once again, that this source command is executing your vimrc in the context of your current buffer, without regard to settings that are already there.

Comment: Well, if I do a plain old `:e` command, everything works as expected. I have to bone up on vim initialization because it confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: What I don't understand is I removed the ftdetect/cheat.vim file completely and just dropped this right into .vimrc: `au BufNewFile,BufRead */.cheat/* set filetype=cheat`. One would assume that it would reload detect the cheat filetype based on that but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes... :e executes filetype detection and therefore filetype plugins again, as if you were editing the file anew (note that it basically reads the file from disk, so save first or when prompted if you so desire)

Comment: For future reference, [vi.se] does exist (I see you have rep there!), and a question like this would be greatly helped by (1) the vimrc file (which you can debug—we have a canonical reference for that) and (2) a more precise description of what steps you take, what you expect, and what the result is (much of which we had to dig out in these comments)

Comment: Well, the OP had all the info I had at the time. As I uncovered more info I posted in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The best long-term solution is to avoid having your vimrc overwrite filetype settings if executed directly by using local options and similar, but the simplest fix is often to re-edit the file. Type

```
:edit
```

And hit Enter.

This can be shortened to just `:e` in interactive use, and a mapping is easily created:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>e :edit<CR>
```

I suggest reading the help pages on vim’s startup, init files, source command, edit command, and the various ways to tune things local to a single buffer (e.g., `setlocal`, `map-<buffer>`, autocmd pattern `<buffer>`).

Comment: Actually, I know what's going on now. The filetype is only detected during `BufNewFile` or `BurRead`. Resourcing vim doesn't trigger either of those events. That's why the settings are getting ignored.

Comment: Not ignored. Overwritten. Unless you were wanting resourcing vimrc to also pick up your changes to a filetype plugin, which was not clear from your question

Comment: I'm trying to fix it with: `nnoremap <silent> sv :so $MYVIMRC<CR><bar>:execute "<silent>setlocal filetype=vim"<cr>` but no luck.

Comment: Oops, was missing a colon. Getting closer though.

Comment: Why would your global source mapping set the filetype that doesnt make any sense—if i did that in a C file it would suddenly get vim filetype settings. Thats also not how `<silent>` works (check the help)

Comment: Because I'm pretty much a clueless dummy when it comes to this.